# Google Colaboratory : Import Data, stack size exceeded?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import data form my folder with this code

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

but it gives me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-3ff52e25531b> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import files
      2 
----> 3 uploaded = files.upload()
      4 
      5 #for fn in uploaded.keys():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/files.py in upload()
     70     result = _output.eval_js(
     71         'google.colab._files._uploadFilesContinue("{output_id}")'.format(
---> 72             output_id=output_id))
     73     if result['action'] != 'append':
     74       # JS side uses a generator of promises to process all of the files- some

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py in eval_js(script, ignore_result)
     37   if ignore_result:
     38     return
---> 39   return _message.read_reply_from_input(request_id)
     40 
     41 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108
MessageError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

which I did not understand. is the reason the data relatively big (22578685bytes) or is it because of javascript?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

My suggestion is to try uploading the file using the file browser instead. (It uses a distinct transport that's much more efficient, particularly for large files.)

[image]

Does that correct the problem?

Answer (score 19):

I was using colab in **safari on my mac** then it gave me this error. Tried uploading from the button above mentioned but did not work.

Simply ran the colab in **Google Chrome** and it worked smoothly for me.

Answer (score 5):

If @bob-smith s suggestion doesn't work, try using a different browser. I tried different workarounds but the problem laid in that I was using brave browser.

Try Chrome instead, for me it did the trick.